# Flashing screen with hyperlinks <a href> with mobile chrome responsive.menu wordpress

Tags: wordpress, responsive, mobile-chrome

The entire screen flashes blue briefly with mobile chrome and hyperlinks using responsive.menu in wordpress. I'm looking to remove this effect.

You can reproduce the issue by using chrome and putting the browser in mobile mode. Navigate the browser to http://responsive.menu and use their menu on the right hand side, simply click the plus and minus arrows on the sub menu to demonstrate the effect.

Also, a screen shot and screen cast:

Shot:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B-M6Yes83t08RjJ1T1IxU2JDTjg

Screen cast:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B-M6Yes83t08cTRJbXNNTGdjcmM

**From the author of the component:**

> it is due to the fact that for mobiles to detect a click event on the
>   body of the site without reverting to loading the jQuery mobile
>   library, I have added `cursor: pointer;` to the body.
>
> This has the side effect of creating these blue flashes on mobile
>   Chrome as the browser now thinks that the whole body is a link. The
>   quickest option is to turn off the "Click to close menu on body
>   clicks" option while I see if there is a workaround in the long term.
>   The only way around this I can think of is to load jQuery mobile
>   separately, but I was always reluctant to do this.

**Question update:**

This only happens on chrome mobile - how do you emulate safari and firefox mobile behavior?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How do you remove this effect as it only happens on chrome mobile.

Comment: I suggest you try https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/responsive-menu or other contacts for the developer.

Comment: Already did. The fact is it's a quirk for Chrome mobile. Firefox, safari do not exhibit the behavior.